# Is Mongo aggregation with a date range broken?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents with a string field "action" and a "receivedTimestamp" Date field, all the values of which are from March and April 2016.  I'm trying to count how many there are of each action in a date range.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 68 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$gte": new Date("2016-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 68 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$gte": new Date("2017-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 68 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$lte": new Date("2017-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 0 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$lte": new Date("2016-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 0 results.

So I'm really starting to think Mongo aggregation with a date range broken.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Couldn't it just be that all of your documents have a `receivedTimestamp` that is greater than `new Date("2017-01-01")` ?

Comment: No, they're all from March and April 2016.

Comment: Horrible title, and before you ask if widely used software is basically broken you should consider that fact, "Widely used". So of course it is not broken, but ***your data** likely is. So forget the 68 results, but show us the **4 results** as documents where we can all reproduce this ourselves. Or alternately happily point out what is exactly wrong with your recorded data, which is of course what the real problem here will be.

Comment: No problem with my data.  The solution was to use ISODate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by switching to ISODate:

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$gte": new ISODate("2016-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 68 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$gte": new ISODate("2017-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 0 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$lte": new ISODate("2016-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 0 results.

When I run this:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"receivedTimestamp": {"$lte": new ISODate("2017-01-01")}}}, 
  {"$group": {"_id":   "$action", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

I get 68 results.

This the behavior I would expect to see.  I'm not aware of any documentation of the requirement to use an ISODate in this context.